# Finding lookalike for large number of users

Tags: clustering, apache-spark, similarity

We have a large user-base, within which we want to find lookalikes, around 25-30 Million, for the users, we have data such as show liked by the user, genre liked etc.

What we need to do is extrapolate our custom list (ex: find lookalikes for a list of 100,000 and extend it to 300,000) from our final result of lookalike_job_data, when we need to use the IDs somewhere.

This is written in Java and we use Threadpool for parallelizing:

Our current approach is, we have all our data in Apache Solr, as our data is updated incrementally, we query for 'term-frequency' of a shows_watched by a user, sort them as per 'term-frequency', we don't take into consideration the shows which have 'term-frequency' as 1 
-> regard them as new users

or users which only have 2-3 shows in their list.

Then we query for users who have watched the same shows in pairs.
For ex. if we get 5 shows which have 'term-frequency' 
such as sh1-> 7, sh2->4, sh3->5, sh4->6, sh5->14

We make pairs of 3 among them which are in 'AND' with 'OR' over all of the pairs as if our query will be as:

Find me users, that have watched :

(sh1 AND sh2 AND sh3) OR (sh2 AND sh3 sh4) and so on

Our query also uses 'frange'( a feature in '**SOLR**' to limit a value) which limits the results to a distance from the base user.

It is applied to 'dist' (feature in '**SOLR**') function, which gets the distance of other's shows to the base user 
(same shows for which we the term-frequency).

So this will be our cluster for that user, and we ignore the rest of the user's in this cluster but still, this approach is slow for our usage, We'll probably run this job for full data once/twice a week and incrementally assign the new user's to existing clusters b/w them.

This process is still slow, can someone recommend a better approach, I am open to anything.

For 2 months our data size is around 140GBs.

Our SOLR runs on an AWS *i3.2xlarge*(8 core, 60GB ram, 2TB instance store SSD) machine,
and we fire queries from 4core, 16 GB ram machine

We initially have our data in S3.

Comment: So just to summarize:

1. You have lots of data


2. You want to find the closest "types" of users to the ones you have in your DataBase?


3. You have some functions you can perform on your data?

Comment: Ya, sums it up in brief

Comment: For 140GB of data I would suggest increasing your computation power. I didn't get the explanation of your process so I'll just ask why don't you use matrix factorization + clustering techniques as it is widely used for user recommender system ?

Comment: I'd amend @debzsud's suggestion to use approximate similarity search instead of clustering. FB has a library called [FAISS](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1373769912645926/faiss-a-library-for-efficient-similarity-search/) to do this at scale. Matrix factorization is an efficient way of simulataneously finding representations of both the users and the items. Since your problem has a concept of items (shows), matrix factorization should apply. If users don't rate shows, use _implicit_ matrix factorization.